# how to stop the code if one statement is not reached in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I want to know how to stop the code if one of the if statements returns a false, because I noticed that in my code, If i'm doing an edit profile: for example when a user entered a wrong email but his username was accepted, I will receive UIAlertController for the wrong Email but it will update the username, I don't want that. Is there a better practice ? thanks

```js
@IBAction func update(sender: UIButton) {
    let user:PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
    let username = username.text
    let email = email.text

    var valid:Bool = true
    self.view.endEditing(true)

    
    if(valid){
     \\ look to find error with mutliple check if inside
        valid = false
        
        
        }else{
            user.setObject(emails!, forKey: "email")
  
        }
    
    if(valid){
        \\ look to find errorwith mutliple check if inside
        valid = false
        
        
    }else{
        user.setObject(usernames!, forKey: "username")
        
    }
    
    if(valid){
        let spinner = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated:true)
        spinner.labelText = "Please Wait"
        
        myUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
            if(success){
                print("awesome")
            }else{
                self.displayAlert(error!.localizedDescription, dismiss: false)
            }
        })
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should `return` if a condition is failed, to cancel to process:

```
func updateProfile() {

    if false == username.isValid() {
       // show UIAlertController wrong username format
       return
    }

    if false == email.isValid() {
        // show UIAlertController wrong email format
        return
    }

    sendUpdateProfile()
}
```

The above code just is pseudocode, you should implement it yourself.

**EDITED**

See this tutorial and learn how to update the profile with Parse
http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/update-user-profile-details-with-swift-and-parse/

Comment: email.isValid how to set up that ?from where did you define it ? and what's sendUpdateProfile ?

Comment: `isValid` is the method you write to validate the new email is right or wrong format. Just pseudocode with `return` command after a condition is failed. You should implement logic by yourself.

Comment: This is also a pseudocode, which is a function you use to `update profile`

Comment: how to write this function update profile ( sendUpdateProfile)?

Comment: From your question, `but it will update the username, I don't want that`. Use your code.

Comment: But sendUpdateProfile will be a func not just sendUpdateprofile()

Comment: I tried your method with a button but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe if you have a tutorial or an example u saw somewhere it will help to better understand if i missed something thanks

Comment: Please update your answer with your code. I don't seem to understand what you want.

Comment: Updated tutorial link

Comment: it's from this tuto i created my profile ! but i'm asking just where is my fault in my code ? please